# Populating Webform Tables

Tags: webforms

I am new to Drupal and have been working with Webform module to generate a custom form. One of the requirements for the form is to show a table where a user can add upload documents like this:

[image: sample webform table]

I created a new webform and started adding fields. As I added the 'table' field, it had option to set table Header (th) but not rows (td). I am not very familiar with the idea of hooks. Can someone please tell me how I can add rows? And if it is not possible to be done via the UI, then in what files the code must be added?

I am using Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

Composite elements do not support file uploads. If there is a finite amount of documents you could manually build a table. The [Table element was recently hidden](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2952842) because it was impossible to document. Here is an [example of table layout](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-03-10/webform.webform.issue_2951650_table.yml) within a Webform.